# Cannot connect RDS Database to a Lambda Function (Using serverless framework)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, amazon-vpc

I want to connect my RDS Database table with my lambda function, for this, I have created a lambda function and used knex.js and postgres database in rds, I got the knex object, but I cannot work with any query.

To give some more information about the services,

- RDS database server security group can be access from anywhere
- I have given the vpc in the serverless.yml file in the function.
- Region of both lambda and rds are different, but not sure whether it is the problem.

My serverless function

- note: this knex code is working when I tried this separately.

```
module.exports.storeTransaction = async (event) => {  
  ...  
  knex('Transactions')
  .select('*')
  .then(response => {
    console.log('response is ');
    console.log(response);
  })
  ...
};
```

Serverless.yml file

```
service: <service-name>

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies

functions:
  storeEmail:
    handler: handler.storeTransaction
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - <security-group-id-of-rds>
      subnetIds:
        - <subnet-id-of-rds>
        - <subnet-id-of-rds>
        ...
      region:
        - us-east-1a
    events:
      - http:
          path: email/store
          method: post
          cors: true
```

So can you identify my issue on why I can't connect my rds db with lambda function, and let me know what I did wrong or what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that RDS and Lambda are in different regions, which means they are also in different VPCs, as a VPC cannot span across multiple regions. Although you can enable Inter VPC Peering (https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#Peering_Connections).

Consider that when you deploy a lambda function in a VPC, it won't have internet access as long as you don't attach a NAT Gateway to that VPC/subnet.

If the RDS is open to the world (and does it really need to be??), you can try to deploy in the same region (without a VPC) and verify if that works.

Comment: I removed the vpc for my lambda and it's working fine, Thank you.